# Excel PowerPivot Measure For cumulative total (of only the visible cells in a Pivot Table) for underlying OLAP data

Tags: excel, powerpivot, cumulative-sum, measure

I am trying to provide on of our FHF fundraising campaign managers with a tool they can use to help them pick postcodes to send a campaign to.

**Spoecifcally, I'm seeking help writing an Excel PowerPivot Measure for a cumulative total that counts only the visible cells in a Pivot Table and wherein the source data is OLAP (i.e. an Excel Data Model - which seems to carry some constraints to possible solutions)**

The linked worksheet is a simplified example of the excel worksheet tool I want to give to the Campaign Manager in a Fundraising setting https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3pfc8ix2ekduoocsa90zs/minReprodExample_share1.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=m6gqf5zbjxhl6dzkjq653it3d

We have two predictive models both giving different predicted response rates per postcode

The 'data' tab contains the raw data
The 'modelA_pivot' tab contains a pivot table ranking the raw data according to the predicted response rates from ModelA
'model_pivotB' does the identical pivot for ModelB

Focussing just on the 'modelA_pivot' tab for now
you can see a slicer that allows the campaign manager to exclude postcodes with only 3,000 addresses
(or some other threshold level of their choosing)

The slicer's exclusion of a single postcode with 3,000 addresses in this example is why you see the rank column in the pivot run; 1, 3, 4, 5
(i.e. missing rank 2 postcode with 3,000 addresses)

In the pivot, the last column - 'addressCount_postcodeCumulative_modelA' - is based on an excel Power Pivot 'Measure'
And the current formula of the measure is

```
=VAR rankCurrent = MAX([rank_modelA])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM([addressCount_postcodePer]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(data),
        [rank_modelA] <= rankCurrent
    )
)
```

You can see in the 'modelA_pivot' tab the 'addressCount_postcodeCumulative_modelA' column
doesn't work or make sense. As it includes the cumulative total of ALL addresses (including the 3,000 addresses that are excluded from the pivot)

**Can anyone help me with a 'Measure' formula that sums only the addresses of the postcodes that are visible and included in the pivot table**

FYI and in case anyone is wondering, why a 'Measure'; I am using excel Power Query and Power Pivot so if/when the data upstream changes, the data team will be able to refresh this worksheet with a single click (more or less), and the campaign manager still gets to use excel (the tool they know and like)

But, the use of excel Power Query and Power Pivot and setting this up as an excel Data Model (which uses OLAP structured data)
is also injecting constraints which I'm hoping to fit the answer to this puzzle inside
Constraints such as;

- I can't seem to put calculated fields onto the pivot table, and
- I don't want to just add conventional excel columns on the side of the pivot table as the size of the pivot table is dynamic depending on choices of the Campaign Manager (like their choice of threshold # addresses in the slicer)

Comment: Have you tried replacing `ALL` with `ALLSELECTED` in your measure?

Comment: Hey Jos. No, I haven't. If yoru still online... could you guide me as to what the measure code would look like with ALLSELECTED

Comment: As I said, just replace `ALL` with `ALLSELECTED` in your current measure `addressCount_postcodeCumulative_modelA`.

Comment: Sorry - yes. Done. It works perfectly. Your my saviour. Greatly indebted :)